# Zlib C++ boost inflate socket data

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, zlib

I am receiving data from a server through a socket using boost asio, and the data is compressed using zlib.  I need to inflate this data once I get it.  Is there an easy way to do this using boost? Or any other way?  The code is C++.

Comment: Can't you just use zlib to inflate the data as you receive it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Boost.Iostreams library includes a zlib decompressor filter [(link)](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/zlib.html). You can read a chunk of data from the socket into a buffer then decompress, or you can (hopefully, but I haven't tried it myself) chain the filter onto the socket and read decompressed data straight out of the end of the filter.

Note, however, that you have to re-compile boost with zlib support. [(link)](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/iostreams/doc/installation.html)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about boost, but you can download zLib .h and .lib link your code and call uncompress.